# Rank of block matrix

Tags: matrices

Given a $q\times n$ matrix $E$ whose rank is $n$. Imagine that every element $[e_{ij}]$ of $E$ is replaced by a $m\times p$ matrix $F_{ij}$, whose rank is $p$. And in general, each $F_{ij}$ is different with each other. Now the problem is: Is the rank of the new matrix $E_F$ equal to $np$?

Answer (score 1):

You're throwing away all the elements of the original matrix, so the fact that its original rank was $n$ has no effect (apart from telling you that $q \ge n$).  The new matrix has at least rank $p$
because it has submatrices of rank $p$, but that's about all you can say.  Its rank could be anything from $p$ to $np$.